# UIViewController dismiss few controllers (iOS 4.3 and higher)

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have hierarchy of UIViewControllers that have been presented using presentModalViewController methods.

I have singleton that grab all presented view controllers to an array.

For example I presented controller A then B and then C. Each controller I inserted to the index 0.

So I have hierarchy as below

C

B

A

this is my singleton

@implementation PresentHelper

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.viewControllers = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
    return self;
}

+ (PresentHelper *)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static PresentHelper *sharedInstance = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (void)backToViewControllerA
{
    for (UIViewController *controller in self.viewControllers) {
        [controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
    [self.viewControllers removeAllObjects];
}

@end
```

In `UIViewController` C I call `backToViewControllerA` method.

So when I was debugging this method I was wondering why `- viewDidLoad` method (for each controller in self.viewControllers) invoked after this line`[controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];` as I think it should not work like this, but it works.

So, maybe this is not one way how to return back to the view controller A, but my question is connected to viewDidLoad method in any case.

Also this is my code below how I present each controller. I have base class and each (A, B, C controllers are inherited from it).

```
- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    PresentHelper *presentHelper = [PresentHelper sharedInstance];
    [presentHelper.viewControllers insertObject:modalViewController atIndex:0];
    [super presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated:animated];
}
```

Also got this message

NSArray was mutated while being enumerated

So as I think after dismiss I lose my object and maybe this is my problem.

Comment: So...is you question about the viewDidLoad behaviour, or are you asking what is the best way to get from C to A? Is the _entire_ reason for the Singleton just to facilitate navigation back to A from C? Does the solution need to be iOS4.3 compatible?

Comment: the question is about best way. I found strange behavior and this is connected to mutated my array and as I think is not connected to viewDidLoad. thanks

Comment: Does it need to work on iOS4.3? This is an important distinction regarding possible solutions.

Comment: yes it has to work for 4.3 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem like a good use of a Singleton.

There are a number of ways you can get back to A. You shouldn't need to construct extra delegate methods or properties, as each controller has a reference to the previous one through it's `presentingViewController` property. (*I'll rephrase that... for iOS5+, you can use the built-in viewController property `presentingViewController`*). To stay compatible with iOS4.3, make a property and put it in your  base class `@interface`:

```
    @property (nonatomic, assign) UIViewController* presentingController;
```

Also in your base clase interface, declare a method:

```
    - (void) dismissBackToA;
```

In the `@implementation`, `@synthesize` your property and define `dismissBackToA`

```
 - (void) dismissBackToA
{
    if ([[self presentingController] respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissBackToA)]) {
           [[self presentingController] performSelector:@selector(dismissBackToA)];
    }
}
```

In your modal present code, set a reference to self in the presented VC - eg:

```
   MasterViewController* BViewController = [[BViewController alloc] init];
   BViewController.presentingController = self;
   [self presentModalViewController:BViewController animated:YES];
```

Now all you have to do is override `dismissBackToA` in your AViewController subclass:

```
- (void) dismissBackToA
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

This will allow you to daisychain any number of modal viewControllers... the generic `dismissBackToA` will 'unwind' the chain back to A. A's override method will dismiss it's modal (B). This *should* wipe out all of the other controllers in the chain. `presentController` is acting pretty much as a standard delegate - I've overspecified it to emphasise it's similarity to `presentingViewController` in iOS5+. I'm a bit rusty on nonArc memory, but I think that needs to be assigned not retained.

I'm afraid I can't test this 100% as I don't have a iOS4.3 simulator at hand...

*update*

You could also just pass a reference to A all the way up the chain and send `[self.referenceToA dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]` whenever you need to, but this way feels a little more generic.

You should also BEWARE that `presentModalViewController:animated:` and `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` are DEPRECATED in 6.0: now you are supposed to use

```
- presentViewController:animated:completion: 
- dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:
```

which were introduced in 5.0.

They still work, but take that as a warning -  you are going to have to be prepared to drop support for 4.3 or make your code conditional on OS version in future.

Comment: I am not sure that I've got your point. I have BaseViewController for A, B and C view controllers (A : BaseViewController, B : BaseViewController and C : BaseViewController). When I tap on the button Home I need to dismiss controller C and B. I have implemented you code in base view controller but maybe we talk about different things.

Comment: I ve got =) I just need to call  [super dismissBackToA] instead of [self dismissBackToA]

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander - check my updated answer, you need to take care in the future as you are using deprecated methods...

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good way to dismiss your controllers. Creating a singleton just for this purpose seems like a bad idea. By far the easiest way, would be to do it in the storyboard using an unwind segue, but this will only work for iOS 6 I think (maybe iOS 5 too). If you want to do it in code, then you  should use delegation or NSNotifications to have A dismiss C (which will also dismiss B).  Also, if you are going to be presenting modal view controllers in code, you shouldn't be using this depreciated method, use presentViewController:animated:completion: instead.

After edit:

You could also do it like this from controller C:

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: OP specifies iOS4.3 and higher... so no Storyboards or no unwind segues allowed.

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander, yeah, I just noticed, and edited my answer.

Comment: what about delegate. for example after dismiss call delegate method in B after in C controller and dismiss them one by one

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander, you could dismiss them one by one if you want, or pass a reference to A along to B then C, so you can make the dismiss call from A which will dismiss any controllers after A. Or do it like in my last edit using presentingViewController.